# how to show loader in non ajax navigation in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I ma using non ajax based navigation in jquery mobile because I want to load and run a specific script on each page. But the problem is that When I use the non ajax based navigation in jquery mobile. The loader doesn't show up. I disabled the ajax by using

```
data-ajax="false"
```

with every anchor link.

Is there any quick way to show loader with each page transition without having to write custom function ?

Comment: I think the only way would be to use a custom function, i.e. `$('*[data-ajax=false]').click(function() { $('#loader').fadeIn(100); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that a spinner with ajax disabled is possible. I mean you could flash it for a second before or after the page is loaded but that kinda defeats the purpose. I do however know that loading and running specific script on specific pages is possible. So maybe your question should be how do I get specific scripts to run in specific JQM pages?

Binding to pageinit will help you execute your own javascript for specific pages. The following will only execute when a JQM page with the id of page2  is loaded. Just put this in an external script and link to it in the head of your pages.

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#page2',function(){
    $('#appendMe').append('This text was appended');    
});
```

If you want to load an external script/library use the $.getScript(); method. In my example I am going to load and execute the [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) library when a JQM page with the id of page3 is loaded. Spin.js just puts a little spinner in the page.

```
​​$(document).on('pageinit','#page3',function(){
    $.getScript('http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/dist/spin.min.js', function(){
        //the following code gets executed after spin.js is loaded
        var opts = {
            lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 7, // The length of each line
            width: 4, // The line thickness
            radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
            rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
            left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('spin');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/yQNJF/1/) to convince you I'm not just making this all up. Hehe

Comment: can I do the same with class. I mean for the page with specific class instead of ID ?

Comment: and you are right. Instead f disabling the ajax. I should try to run the function on pageinit

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use classes as well. I don't think I have tried it yet but I'm sure it works just the same.

Comment: one correction in your code. $(document).on('pageinit','#page3',function() doesnt work on jquery mobile instead it uses the $('#page3').live('pageinit',function(). else you guided me in the right direction. thanks

Comment: It works check the jsfiddle example but it does require jQuery 1.7 +. The live() method has been deprecated. I suggest you use delegate or even bind instead if you are pre jQuery 1.7. There were alot of reported issues with live. The docs suggest this here http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1 and on method is giving an error that the object has no method .on ()

Answer (score 1):

There is a client-side method to show/hide the loader:

`$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();`

`$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();`

Comment: Yeah but that won't work while switching to a new page with ajax disabled.