# leave javascript intact when dynamically loading a page into jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In a jquery mobile page, I create a link to load another page dynamically:

```
<a href="advertiser.php" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Add New Advertiser</a>
```

When the page gets loaded, the javascript that is in the page's `<head>` is stripped away.

Is there any way to have jquery mobile leave the loaded page's scripts intact?

Comment: what you mean by **scripts are stripped away.** ?

Comment: answer is here btw http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you because of lack in details. 
Try to add: data-prefetch to your link.

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to do exactly what your talking about. I do however believe there is a simpler way to accomplish the same goal. Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681125/how-to-show-loader-in-non-ajax-navigation-in-jquery-mobile/10682189#10682189). It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the page are not much heavy then you can create the next page (to be opened) in the same document i.e.

```
 <div data-role="advertiser" id="Login">
```

and open it with link

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="forward" data-theme="a" href="#advertiser" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left">Add New Advertiser</a>
```

in this way even if you go back and forth , your script will not be refreshed